# using "set-cookies" returned in response headers

Tags: reactjs, http, cookies, axios, setcookie

I have an API where its response returns "set-ccokies" in the response headers. I'm not sure how to use it.
basically I need to save in the browser cookies the token I get from the "set-cookies". I'm using Axios and I'm not able to access the value of the "set-cookie" .
what do I miss? how can I store cookies in the browser that are returned from the API call?
look in the internet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.